# Show that $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ iff $\lim _{n \to \infty } P [\cup _{m=n } A _n ]=0$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Show that $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ if and only if $\lim _{n \to \infty } P [\cup _{m=n } A _n ]=0$
, where $P $  is a probability measure.

*secondly* is it true that   $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ if and only if $\sum _n P [A _n ] < \infty $?

---

Here is my attempt:

Suppose  $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ , then $\exists n _0 : \bigcup _{m \ge n _0 } A _m=\emptyset$.
This implies $\lim _{n \to  \infty } P [\cup _{m=n } A _m ]=0 $.

Conversely if $\lim _{n \to \infty } P [\cup _{m=n } A _n ]=0$, then $\forall \epsilon >0 $ $\exists n _0: P [\cup _{m = n _0 } A _m ]<\epsilon $
This implies $ \cup _{m = n _0 } A _m $ is an decreasing sequence (?). Which implies $\cap _{n=0 } \cup _{m=n } A _m =\emptyset$ (?)

---

Now for  $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ iff $\sum _n P [A _n ] < \infty $,

If  $\sum _n P [A _n ] < \infty $, then $P [A _n ] \to 0 $, and this implies $\cup _{m=n } A _m $ decreases to the empty set with $n $ (?).

Conversely if $\lim \sup A _n = \emptyset$ then $P [A _m ]\to 0 $, and this does not generally imply that $\sum _n P [A _n ] < \infty $.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m)=0$. Define $B_k=\bigcup\limits_{m=k}^{\infty} A_m$. Note that $B_1\supset B_2 \supset B_3 \supset \cdots$. Hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(\bigcup\limits_{m=n}^{\infty} A_m)=P(\bigcap\limits_{k=1}^{\infty} B_k)=P(\limsup A_n)=0$. However this does not imply $\limsup A_n=\emptyset$. So the other implication is false. Just get an $\omega \in \Omega$ for which $P(\{\omega\})=0$, and you will obtain contradictions to most of the results. So essentially if you replace $\limsup A_n=\emptyset$ by $P(\limsup A_n)=0$, then if $\sum P(A_n)<\infty$ we have
$$P(B_k)\stackrel{\mbox{Boole}}{=}\le \sum_{m=k}^{\infty} P(A_k) \to 0, \ \ \mbox{as} \ \ k\to \infty$$
Hence
$$P(\limsup A_n)=\lim_{m\to\infty}P(\bigcap_{k=1}^{m} B_k) \le \lim_{m\to\infty} P(B_m) =0$$
The other implication is not true in general. But it holds when $A_n$ are independent. This result is known as Borel-Cantelli Lemma.

Comment: Thank, I didn't see your asnwer before now. I wonder if the rather famous probabilist Varadhan has a missprint then in his lecture notes here. file:///C:/Users/Elias%20Trollmo/Downloads/[S._R._S._Varadhan]_Probability_theory(BookZZ.org).pdf
(This is from excercise 1.13)

Comment: wrong linc
http://dlx.bookzz.org/genesis/73000/e051235a80f05bc7baef3ef31301679a/_as/[S._R._S._Varadhan]_Probability_theory(BookZZ.org).pdf